# I think SE is down

Tags: support

### Is all back up for me now. I think it was a DNS problem?

I am seeing lots of errors on Ask Ubuntu and I can't get to Se Meta.

It looks like this:

[image]

and this is Chrome console.

[image]

Comment: @Oli thanks, I couldn't insert when I posted from the button, and I'd forgotten the syntax.

Comment: Try reloading the page...  I think it did not reader right, meaning it didn't load all of the way.

Comment: @Andew, nope didn't work, I even restarted the browser and tried in incognito. And also, site.SE (including meta) wasn't working. The errors show something to do with SE not being found...

Comment: Humm.  I have the exect same issure before many of times and that did fix it.

Comment: @Tim Try after clearing cache of web-browser.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't had problems today - but you can check [here](https://twitter.com/StackStatus) usually to see if there are any current site-wide issues/maintenance etc.

Other thing that can be done is try a different browser, computer, internet connection, planet etc. You can also check using a browser inspection tool for any 404 errors and stuff.

Comment: +1 for planet ;) you've guessed already?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, AU is back for me...

<s>[stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) is still down for me though, as are all site.SE.com sites.</s>

<s>Edit: meta.SE back, and all site.SE but not SO.</s>

Final Edit: All back up for me. DNS error?